# Why does this not compile? Can't assign new value to String member of anonymous class

Tags: java, variable-assignment, anonymous-class

Why can't I assign a new value to the String member of the anonymous class in the code below?

When attempting to compile to throws the error: Unresolved compilation problems: Syntax error on token ";" ,, expected. However this is thrown on the line `String s = "Value";` which works fine when the line `s = "New Value";` is commented out.

```
public class Example {
    // nested class to help us out
    private class SomeClass {
    }

    // entry point
    public static void main (String args[]){
        Example e = new Example();
        e.performTest();
    }

    // performs the test
    private void performTest(){
        // anonymous class to test
        SomeClass nc = new SomeClass() {
            String s = "Value";
            s = "New Value";
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself, what does it being an anonymous class have to do with it? Does it really? What happens if you try it in a regular, top-level class?

Comment: You are right... I was treating it like a method, not a class. Darn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement `s = "New Value";` is not within a method.  It's anonymous class, but it's still a class.  The problem is equivalent to

```
public class SomeSubClass {
   String s = "Value";
   s = "New Value";
}
```

The problem should be more apparent now.

Place the statement in a method or constructor, or initialize `s` to `"New Value"` instead of `"Value"`.